# Segmentation fault using rb_reg_match in C

Tags: c, ruby

I am trying to use the rb_reg_match function in C as I would in Ruby, but when running the following code but I get a SEGV error:

```
#include <ruby/ruby.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    char *pattern = "t";
    VALUE re = rb_reg_new(pattern, strlen(pattern), 0);
    const char *str;

    VALUE rstring = rb_str_new("title", 5);
    rb_reg_match(re, rstring);
};
```

here is my output:

```
/home/roroco/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/3e79ffef/3e79ffef/Debug/ex/ex
Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for rb_reg_new and rb_str_new?

Comment: @Greg Yes, of course

Comment: Have you at least compiled your problem with debugging information and run it in a debugger so that you can see where your segfaulting?

Comment: @anxvonial, please include than link here.